# ActiveMQ WebSocket flooding the log with NPE warn

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

ActiveMQ 5.14.1 is working well but is flooding the log with that exception.

Connecting to:

```
<transportConnector name="wss" uri="wss://0.0.0.0:443?maximumConnections=5000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
```

Exception:

```
2016-12-07 11:28:56,106 | WARN  | / | org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler | qtp1782247761-29
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ws.jetty9.WSServlet.doGet(WSServlet.java:88)[activemq-http-5.14.1.jar:5.14.1]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)[tomcat-servlet-api-8.0.24.jar:]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.servlet.WebSocketServlet.service(WebSocketServlet.java:167)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)[tomcat-servlet-api-8.0.24.jar:]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1129)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.7.0_80]
```

Is that a real bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be the same as this issue ([AMQ-6491](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-6491)) which happens when you try and send a GET request to the broker for whatever reason.  Normally you wouldn't do that but some people seem to have used it to hack around limitations in Chrome or the like.  This is fixed in the ActiveMQ 5.14.2 release.

Comment: That's it. Thank you!